# Is there a way to get user events through stackexchange API?

Tags: api, stackexchange-api

I want to get all available events for certain (one) user on StackOverflow such as questions answered, accepted, posted questions, posted comments etc. Something similar to activity events in github API https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/.

The closest thing I found was this https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events. However, this returns events from all users.

Is there a way to get such data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the `users` methods, like [`/users/{ids}/answers`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) and friends, as described somewhere down on this page in [the API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Update:

The [`reputation-history`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history) returns all *public* [reputation events](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation-history). There also is the [`full-reputation-history`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) that returns both public and private events.

Comment: That's what I initially found. Just to make sure (in case I missed it) There's NO way to get list of all events in single API call? Similarly to github events?

Comment: Perhaps the reputation-history will be useful. I've updated my answer.